# Unterschied zwischen annehmen, mutmaßen und vermuten

Tags: word-usage

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen annehmen, mutmaßen und vermuten?

Danke im Voraus!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In dieser Antwort gehe ich davon aus, dass die Wörter nur im Sinne von *Vermutung* betrachtet werden (Annehmen hat daneben noch weitere Bedeutungen).

Die Unterschiede sind wohl nur marginal und in vielen Fällen dürfte der Empfänger wohl keine Unterschiede verstehen. Beispielsweise listet  [Duden.de](http://https:/duden.de/rechtschreibung/mutmaszen) für Mutmaßen unter Bedeutungsübersicht *Vermuten* und *Annehmen*. Auch bei den Synonymen gibt es sehr große Überschneidungen.

Nach meinen Sprachgefühl lassen sich jedoch die folgende Feinheiten ausmachen. (Im Beispiel geht es um eine Unsicherheit darüber ob eine Person noch kommt):

- **Ich nehme an, dass er kommt noch**

Man geht relativ fest davon aus, dass die Person noch erscheint und handelt so, als ob es gewiss wäre.

> Ich nehme an, dass er noch kommt und halte ihm das Essen warm.

- **Ich vermute, dass er kommt noch**

Auch hier geht man davon aus, dass die Person noch erscheint. Die Unsicherheit ist jedoch etwas größer als im ersten Fall. Die Unsicherheit wird etwas stärker betont.

- **Mutmaßlich kommt er noch**

Hier wird noch eher verdeutlicht, dass es sich um eine Spekulation handelt. betont aber, dass man es nicht genau weiß.

Interessant ist vielleicht noch, dass [Duden.de](http://duden.de) für *Vermuten* und *Annehmen* ein leicht höhere Häufigkeit im Vergleich zu *Mutmaßen* angibt. Dies spiegelt sich so auch in der Alltagssprache wieder, in der *Mutmaßen* eher selten vorkommt. Wie @ChristianGeiselmann in seinem Kommentar angemerkt hat findet es eher in förmlicher Sprache bzw. in höheren Stilebenen Verwendung.

Comment: Soweit stimme ich zu. Was mir fehlt, ist der Hinweis, dass mit den verschiedenen Wörtern auch verschiedene Stilebenen einhergehen (können). *Mutmaßen* wird man in einer Alltagsunterhaltung kaum (außer man spräche ironisch). Das Wort kommt eher in behördensprachlichen Äußerungen vor oder in sogenannten höheren Stilebenen. *Vernuten* ist einigermaßen neutral im Stil. *Annehmen* ist auch neutral, aber gleichzeitig auch das "leichtgängigste" der drei Verben in mündlicher Kommunikation.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Habe mich dazu erstmal nicht geäußert, da ich mir eher unsicher war. Das Mutmaßen in der Alltagssprache eher selten vorkommt ist wohl unumstritten, aber bei Vermuten vs. Annehmen fällt es mir persönlich schwer Unterschiede zu erkennen.

Comment: *Mutmaßen* ist in meinem Sprachgebrauch ein "totaler Schuß ins Blaue", während *vermuten* und *annehmen* normalerweise etwas mehr Grundlage haben. Der "amtliche" Sprachgebrauch ist ein bißchen anders - Dort ist *mutmaßen* einigermaßen "professionell", während *annehmen* und *vermuten* einen eher "laienhaften" Ton haben.

Answer (score 2):

Das Verb *vermuten* kann universell eingesetzt werden.

> Sie vermutet einen Betrug.

Das Verb *annehmen* hat viele Bedeutungen. Die Bedeutung *einen Gedanken haben* kann man nur mit Objektsätzen wirklich klar formulieren, weil man dort ein erklärendes Verb leicht einflechten kann.

> Sie nimmt einen Betrug an. *(klingt komisch!)*
>
> Sie nimmt an, dass es sich um einen Betrug handelt.
>
> Sie nimmt an, es handele sich um einen Betrug.

Das Verb *mutmaßen* wird immer dann verwendet, wenn man sich eine Geschichte zusammenspinnt:

> Lass uns nicht über Dinge mutmaßen, die weit in der Zukunft liegen.
>
> Mutmaßlich stand der Fahrer unter Alkoholeinfluss.

Oder auch nicht. Irgendwer hat das **gemutmaßt**(==behauptet).